# Varying pressure in container with aperture

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, water

The following diagram pictures a simple container filled with water. At the bottom of the container is a chamber with bottom B. Also directly above the chamber is an aperture that can completely open and close, sealing off the lower chamber or allowing unrestricted water flow.

My question is this: as pictured, is the pressure at B the same as if the aperture were completely open? If not, what is it?

[image: Diagram]

I may be mistaken, but I think the pressure on B is proportional to the width of the aperture opening relative to the width of the chamber itself.

Answer (score 1):

What one could think is that what makes the pressure increase underwater is the weigh of the water column above it.

That is half true. In fact, it is the whole water above that pushes. So the water above the aperture also pushes.

So the pressure doesn't depend on the size of the aperture (at least when the equilibrium is reached). If it was not, the water inside would move until the pressure is homogeneous.

To prove it, you can use fluid statics :
$$\mathbf{\nabla}P = \mathbf{f_v} = -\rho \mathbf{g}$$
With $\mathbf{f_v}$ the force density, $\rho$ the density of water.
And as there is a little hole, one can find the pressure everywhere by following a track from a reference point.